# Cannot use XPath in Appium

Tags: xpath, uwp, appium, winapp

I am automating a UWP application (Windows 10) through Appium + Winapp driver.

I am using Appium inspector to spy the objects in the windows 10 app. There is no name available for the button and therefore trying to use the Xpath

```
/Window/Window[2]/Button[2]
```

I tried clicking the tap button in the Appium inspector and it is clicking on the button name.

If I use the XPath in my selenium code, like the below, it is not working:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//Window[2]/Button[2]").click();
```

Can you please let me know why the script is not able to click the `Button` at the same time the Appium inspector can click it.

My environment is:

- Appium version - 1.9.1
- WinApp Version - 1.1
- Java client - 6.1
- OS - Windows 10

Comment: could be some wait issue, did you try to capture screenshot when it is failing?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, Yeah I have given the sufficient wait time and captured the screenshot as well.  The object is present in the system.